# Check my proof $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \sin(x^2+y^2) \, dx \, dy$ diverges

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, improper-integrals

I am trying to prove that $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \sin(x^2+y^2)\, dx\,dy$ diverges and I did it like this:

$x=r\cos \theta$, $y=r\sin\theta$, $\theta \in [0,2\pi]$, $r\in [0,\infty]$, and the jacobian is $r$:

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \int_{-\infty}^\infty \sin(x^2+y^2) \, dx \, dy=\int_0^{2\pi}\int_{0}^\infty r\sin(r^2) \, dr \, d\theta = 2\pi \int_0^\infty r\sin(r^2) \, dr$$

Use the variable change $v=r^2$, $dv=2r \, dr$ and so:

$$2\pi \int_0^\infty r\sin(r^2)\,dr = 2\pi \int_{0}^{\infty}r\sin(v)\,\frac{dv}{2r}=\pi \int_0^\infty \sin(v) \, dv $$

I checked wolfram, and it says that $\int_0^\infty \sin(x) \, dx$ diverges, so I must conclude that the original integral diverges as well.

But how do I actually prove that $\int_0^\infty \sin(x)\,dx$ diverges?

Comment: Prove that is oscilates infinitely many times.

Comment: The integral does not diverge to infinity instead it does not exist. To prove that then you have to follow the comment by chubakueno.

Comment: on the other hand, $\int \sin(x^2)$ converges.

Comment: @AthanagorWurlitzer The idiosyncrasies of $n$-integration is mind-boggling.

Comment: @CameronWilliams it is a good counter-example to Fubini, when the convergence is only in the sense of Riemann.

Comment: @AthanagorWurlitzer Very good point. I'll keep this in my toolbox of counterexamples ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can compute the limiting integral by writing $$\int_0^\infty \sin(x) dx = \lim_{b\to\infty}\int_0^b \sin(x) dx = \lim_{b\to\infty} ( \cos(b)-1 )$$ We know that the limit $\lim_{b\to\infty} \cos(b)$ diverges. This means the integral diverges as well.

Comment: And is the rest of my proof valid?

Comment: Yes the rest of the proof looks fine to me.

Comment: But [W|A](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=limit+cos+x+as+x-%3Einfinity) says $\lim_{b\to\infty}\cos b=-1\;\text{or}\;1$.

Comment: Wolfram Alpha is wrong in this case. The terms are bounded but they do not converge.